# How to implement progress Indicator in web view?

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to a show the progress indicator before loading the URL in flutter web view and hide after loading the content.

Comment: In order to get some answers you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this in `build` method of your state

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) => FutureBuilder<YourData>(
    future: doRequest(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        ... /* return widget with data from network response */
      } else {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
    });
```

Comment: I not familiar with flutter. What we need to give YourData? option in FutureBuilder in order to open a url

Comment: Actually I didn't see "webview" - wasn't it here before editing? My solution is for showing data in your widget, not as page in webview